# How to display Orchard shape only once?

Tags: html, include, orchardcms, shapes

I have a common shape that renders some HTML code to display an error dialog.

The HTML code **needs** to be included only once throughout the whole web site. For scripts and styles Orchard provides the `Script.Include()` and `Style.Include()` methods.

I wonder whether there is something similar for HTML code, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many options to do this

- Can you add your code to Layout.cshtml in the theme
- Create a new widget and attach the shape field then create it on the default layer (so on all pages) with the name of your shape in the shape field
- Add the shape in a filter, or anywhere else you have access to the WorkContext :)

Code written from memory, may not compile

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Orchard;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement;
using Orchard.Mvc.Filters;
using Orchard.UI.Admin;

public class MyFilter : FilterProvider, IResultProvider {
    private readonly dynamic _shapeFactory;
    private readonly WorkContext _workContext; 

    public MyFilter(WorkContext workContext, IShapeFactory shapeFactory)
    {
        _workContext = workContext;
        _shapeFactory = shapeFactory;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // should only run on a full view rendering result
        if (!(filterContext.Result is ViewResult)) return;

        // front end only
        if (AdminFilter.IsApplied(new RequestContext(_workContext.HttpContext, new RouteData()))) return;

        var body = _workContext.Layout.Body;
        body.Add(_shapeFactory.MyShape());
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {}
}
```

Comment: Good answer but i'm searching for a solution that is based on view usage, e.g. i want to write `@Display.MyShape()` in various views but the shape should be rendered only on the first call. I don't think your solutions fit here, any ideas?

Comment: If it is going to be in various views why not just call it from one place? The filter works for that, as does the widget